# Biasing for complementary common-source stage amplifier

Tags: transistors, cmos, common-source

[image]

Why does no current flow through \$R_F\$ in the absence of signals in Fig 5.47(b)?

**This can only happen if \$V_x = V_\text{out}\$. How is that guaranteed??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Why does no current flow through RF in the absence of signals in Fig
> 5.47(b)?*

*In the absence of signals*  <--- I take this to mean that \$V_{IN}\$ is open circuit and the gates are left to find there own level but, what level can it be? Well,  the gates don't take any current (that can be assumed fairly well) and, the impact of this is simply that there can be no potential difference across \$R_F\$ and, that inevitably means that \$V_{X}\$ must equal \$V_{OUT}\$.

If the gates do produce leakage current, it can be reasonably assumed that M2's gate current is flowing into M1's leakage path. This is a reasonable assumption because the transistors would be designed and fabricated to have very similar characteristics. Hence, the leakage gate currents do not flow through \$R_F\$.